# How can I share the content of an Adapter?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-arrayadapter

I want to share the full content of an adapter when the user press on the positive button of a dialog.
Tried this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

adapter.add("String1");
adapter.add("String2");
adapter.add("String3");
adapter.add("String4");

dialog.setPositiveButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            for(int i = 0; i <= adapter.getCount(); i++){
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, adapter.getItem(i));
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via")
            );
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work. It makes the app to crash when the Share button is pressed.
Any ideas?

*edit*: **Thanks for all the help. this is the final solution:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
    sb.append(adapter.getItem(i)).append("\n");
}
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (CharSequence) sb );
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you include the error too

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i meant the app just crashes.

Comment: Yes, append the crash logs, so that we know what is really causing the problem because setting final modifier to your adapter shouldn't technically cause any trouble

Comment: You was right, its not the final who makes the app crash, instead, it crashes when the Share intent is created. Edited the thread with the crash log included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, adapter.getItem(i));
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Well, thanks... it did solved my problem. Got new problem now: it shares only the last line of the adapter :)

Comment: that is because you are overwriting same extra in for loop.

Comment: Indeed. Any idea how to overcome this issue? I need to loop through every line of the adapter and add all of the them to the intent.

Comment: you can add the text into a array list and add this arraylist to bundle and finally add bundle to the intent.

Comment: I managed to overcome it with StringBuilder... Thanks anyway buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for(int i = 0; **i < adapter.getCount()**; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception at following line:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, adapter.getItem(i));    //at getItem(i)
```

This is because of the condition above it :

```
for(int i = 0; i **<=** adapter.getCount(); i++)
```

As indexing in Java starts from 0, so if adapter count is 8, you should access indexes from 0 to 7.
Hence, if you remove the above condition to the below:

```
for(int i = 0; i **<** adapter.getCount(); i++)
```

There won't be any exception.
Hope that helps.

Regarding your problem #2, sharing whole array adapter data via intent, I think you can create an array list of String to backup adapter's data, and pass that array list in intent via following:

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value);
```

where name is name of extra you're creating (prefixed with package name), and value is Array List of String.